# VS2010 RC: Find In Files error: No files were found to look in

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I hit control + Scroll lock, control + break, and control + every other key on the keyboard.

I have a feeling I am going to see this error in Visual Studio 2050.

Does anyone know how to resolve it when it occurs?

Comment: Can you describe the issue a little more clearly? I use VS2010RC a lot and have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: Is it possible that you are filtering by extension, but looking in a place where no files with that extension exist?  For example, filtering by *.css but looking only in your class library project.

Comment: This is not helpful at all - this question should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was an occurence of an anoying erroring that I have been experiencing in VS for a decade. This time, it was user error. The vaue I had typed bad value for "Look In" should have been "Entire Solution"

http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2007/04/17/Strangest-error-No-files-were-found-to-look-in.-Find.aspx

My apologies